# Topics best practices - AWS SNS and others

Tags: microservices, messaging, message-passing

I'm designing a medium size project that will have few decoupled microservices.

I want to avoid costly architecture mistakes at the very beginning.

What I'm wondering (I googled and didn't found any answer) is if:

A) **SNS topic should be relatively generic** (e.g. "orders-events-topic")

or

B) **there should be separate topic per each event** (e.g. "order-created-topic", "order-accepted-topic", etc.).

I realize that "it depends" - nevertheless I'd like to make a mindful decision.